# Grails delete method

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

The Grails delete method doesn't seem to work.
I wondered if something was wrong.
I couldn't solve it myself.
I would be happy if you could help me.
I am a Japanese who is not good at English. I'm sorry if I make a mistake in English. X(

I referred to the tutorial site.
https://koji-k.github.io/grails-tutorial/tutorials/todo-application/delete.html

**Thing you want to do**
I want to delete the element with the specified id using the delete method.

**Current status**
Can be saved, but cannot be deleted.

**Development environment**
MacOS Mojave
Intellij
Grails Version: 4.0.1
JVM Version: 11.0.2

**Domain**

```
package hoge

class Hoge {
    String name
    String text
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    package hoge
    
    class HogeController {
    
        def index() {
            render(view: '/hoge/index', model: [hoges: Hoge.listOrderById()])
        }
    
        def save() {
            String text = params.text
            String name = params.name
            Hoge newHoge = new Hoge(name: name, text: text)
            // DB save
            if (newHoge.validate()) {
                newHoge.save()
                redirect(controller: "hoge", action: "index")
            } else {
                render(view: '/hoge/index', model: [errorHoge: newHoge, hoges: Hoge.listOrderById()])
            }
    
        }
        def delete() {
            Hoge hoge = Hoge.get(params.long("id"))
            if (hoge) {
                hoge.delete()
                flash.message = "deleted"

            } else {
                flash.error = "TodoId:${params.long("id")} is not found"
            }
        redirect(controller: "hoge", action: "index")
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charaset="UTF-8">
    <title>create page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div style="background-color: #269abc">${flash.message}</div>
    </g:if>
    <g:if test="${flash.error}">
        <div style="background-color: #db7093">${flash.error}</div>
    </g:if>
    <g:renderErrors bean="${errorHoge}" as="list" field="hogeName"/>


    <p>Name and Text</p>
    <g:form controller="hoge" action="save">
        <g:textField name="name" placeholder="name"/>
        <g:textField name="text" placeholder="text"/>
        <g:submitButton name="Add">Add Todo</g:submitButton>
    </g:form>
    <ul>
    <g:each in="${hoges}" var="hoge">
        <li>${hoge.id} ${hoge.name} ${hoge.text}</li>
        <g:link controller="hoge" action="delete" params="['id':hoge.id]">
            Delete
        </g:link>
        <g:link controller="hoge" action="update" params="['id':hoge.id]">
            kousin
        </g:link>
    </g:each>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.0"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:2.0"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:3.0.10"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "hoge"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline"

repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.0.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:3.0.10"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.14.0"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.14.0"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.14.0"
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs(
        '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always', 
        '-noverify', 
        '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
        '-Xmx1024m')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}

webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver '2.45.0'
    geckodriver '0.24.0'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
    systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
}


assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

[It remains even if I try to delete it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmLHa.png)

In case of todo.delete (flush: true)

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI: /hoge/delete/2
Class: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
Message: null
Caused by: no transaction is in progress
```

Comment: What happens when you attempt to delete a record?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown The message "deleted" is displayed, but the element remains. For example, if you delete "abc", "abc" will remain.

Comment: What will happen if you enforce flushing? `hoge.delete(flush:true)`?

Comment: Or try `Hoge.withTtransaction(){}` ? https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html

Comment: A better idea than using `Hoge. withTtransaction(){}` is to move the database logic into a transactional service.  A simple way to see what that looks like is to create a domain class and generate scaffolding for that domain class using `generate-all`. That will show you a basic CRUD example of a transactional GORM Data Service (http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#dataServices).

Comment: @Michal_Szulc　Error 500: An internal server error has occurred. (Details have been added to the question article)

Comment: probably adding @Transactional annotation to `def delete() {` will resolve the issue. However please check scaffolding, which suggested @Jeff. it should help you a lot to understand the basics

Comment: @Michal_Szulc We don't advise making controller actions transactional in recent versions of Grails or GORM.

Comment: `Error 500: An internal server error has occurred.` - The error you showed indicates that a transaction is not running.  Recent versions of Hibernate prevent database operations outside of a transaction (apps really shouldn't be trying to do that anyway).  If you move your operations to a GORM Data Service, that will no longer be an issue.

Comment: @Michal_Szulc  When I added ＠　Transactional to my controller, the element was removed! Thank you very much.

I don't understand what @　Transactional means, so I'll continue to study so that I can understand it.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thank you for giving me an easy-to-understand explanation.

Comment: "When I added `@Transactional` to my controller..." - We don't recommend doing that.  A better idea is to move your transaction boundaries to a transactional service.

Comment: I do not understand transaction service yet, so I will study it. :)

Comment: It's my first time to use Stack Overflow, so I might have forgotten to do something.

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet?

Comment: @Tung Yes.It was solved by saving in the service. Thank you very much.